# Who do we count as "intelligent" and why?

Tags: social-psychology, intelligence, thought

Most of my friends, for instance, say they want an "intelligent" girlfriend. Now, I know this is a philosophical question and a matter of opinion, and there is a [similar question on intelligence](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/7875/how-do-laypeople-form-a-judgement-that-another-person-is-smart-or-intelligent) looking for a scientific or some other formulaic way to label someone as intelligent, what I'm interested in is the social psychology aspect of it: what do they mean? What do people in this day and age think "intelligent" means? Don't they just call that to whoever is counted as intelligent by what they see as social standards? Then what are the universal standards and why?

Comment: Chris - I think it's practically the same, since I explain that the question is psychological and not philosophical and opinionated. Maybe "how does the average person perceive another person to be intelligent?" Sounds better?

Comment: Note: Duplicate of https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/7875/how-do-laypeople-form-a-judgement-that-another-person-is-smart-or-intelligent

Comment: I've seen that one but still wasn't satisfied. Thanks anyway

Comment: check out: Furnham, A. (2001). Self-estimates of intelligence: Culture and gender difference in self and other estimates of both general (g) and multiple intelligences. Personality and Individual Differences, 31(8), 1381-1405.

Comment: "I've seen that one but still wasn't satisfied. Thanks anyway". Would please explain why/how this question is not the same as yours?

Comment: That's not the issue. It's an unanswered question, and it makes no sense to leave it unanswered forever. I will look into Jeromy's cited articles when I have the time

Comment: Although @ArnonWeinberg correctly identified a possible duplicate, this is not strictly a duplicate in some ways, and even if it was, [some duplication is okay](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication).  The duplicate question, to me, is looking for a scientific or some other formulaic way to label someone as intelligent, and as the OP here states here, the question is asking for a pychosocial aspect of how people determine intelligence which, although may not be scientific, is relevant for this site.

Comment: I think that this question is interesting, but it seems off-topic in that form...@holyeyeolo try  to be more specific about your request: for example i would have focused on social psychology: how could  ingroup and outgroup dynamics lead thoughts about intelligence? Could a person be perceived intelligent or not just because he/she' s in a group? Think about that

Comment: The term psychosocial was used by me within my edit of the question and I didn't take into consideration [the difference between the term and social psychology](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120731070817AAnwGsa), so this was my fault and I apologise @holyeyeolo.  I have re-edited to correct this.

Comment: It's alright @Chris. I'm not sure how to make my question viable without changing its core, but I'd like it if the community could do it for me, or even ask a new question with the same principles